# How can i make my bar on hover go on bottom instead of top

Tags: html, css

im getting into nav styling but im stuck in this problem. On hover my text i want the bar go under the text and not on the top.

here is the code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by CodingLab |www.youtube.com/c/CodingLabYT-->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!--<title> All Navigation Menu Hover Animation | CodingLab </title>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span class="text-nav">Home</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #c1f7f5;
}

.text-nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.1ms;
}

.text-nav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  background: #50469e;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.text-nav:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

here is the code in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/navigation-menu-hover-animation-forked-i7p330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to position the line at `bottom: 0;` and add `position: relative;` to your parent element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #c1f7f5;
}

.text-nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.1ms;
}

.text-nav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  background: #50469e;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.text-nav:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <span class="text-nav">Home</span>
    </div>
```